# ScrollView Detecting Scrolling Everywhere

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode, uiscrollview

I have a UIScrollView which is 208pt wide and 280pt tall that contains custom buttons that are 200pt wide and 280 pt tall with 8pt gaps between them. This scrollview has paging enabled but doesn't clip the subviews so that it always snaps to having one button centered but shows the other ones that go off screen. I am trying to make the field in which you can swipe through the buttons take up the full width of the screen, and I am trying to accomplish this with a secondary custom subclass of UIScrollView called PagingView which just has a UIScrollView property and passes all hits on it down to its scrollview. For whatever reason, though, when I  try it without the paging view like this:

```
unsigned height = self.view.frame.size.height;
scrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(60, height - 308, 208, 280)];
scrollView.pagingEnabled = true;
scrollView.clipsToBounds = false;
scrollView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = false;
[self.view addSubview:scrollView];
```

It works, albeit with the field I can interact with the scrollview limited to its frame. However, when I try it with the scrollview:

```
unsigned height = self.view.frame.size.height;
pagingView = [[PagingView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, height - 308, 320, 280)];
scrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(60, height - 308, 208, 280)];
scrollView.pagingEnabled = true;
scrollView.clipsToBounds = false;
scrollView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = false;
pagingView.scrollView = scrollView;
[self.view addSubview:pagingView];
[self.view addSubview:scrollView];
```

It works, but I am able to swipe anywhere on the screen to move through the scrollview. How do I remedy this?

Answer (score 0):

Not clear what you are doing here. You are adding two scroll views to `self.view` but actually you need only one.

The easiest way with least code is to use one plain `UIScrollView`, present your buttons as subviews of correctly sized `UIView`s (you need the gaps around the buttons), and enable paging for the scroll view. Done.

Please note that the measurements you describe do not work out. The scroll view `width` is 208, the button 200, so the wrapper view should have width 208 and the `origin.x` of the button should be 4. The scroll view `height` is 280, the button as well, so there is no vertical margin: wrapper height also 280, button `origin.y` is 0.